# Cannot find .wsf file when running .exe file created by pkg npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, exe, regedit

We are using [regedit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regedit) npm module to save values into windows registry. And we are generating .exe file using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) node module.

When we run this .exe file, it is throwing the following error

> "Input Error: Can not find script file "D:\snapshot[My Folder]\node_modules\regedit\vbs\regList.wsf"

So here the issue is pkg is not packaging .wsf files. It is throwing the same error even when we configured `"**/regedit/vbs/*.wsf"` as part of pkg assets in the package.json file. Any one have solution for this

Comment: This error is thrown when using electron, this might help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/regedit#a-note-about-electron

Comment: Thank you @get_php_workin. That helped me.